# Editing my do while to make it better

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while, joptionpane

I have a question as to how to make my do while loop better. Right now I have the program so that when the user enters whether or not they would like to sell, buy, or discard then they go through the subsequent if statement however what I would like to do instead of asking them if they would like to do said thing again like I have it right now. I would like to ask the user if they would like to barter again and then give them the original three options as opposed to just the one option they originally chose again. Any help would be great.

```
int ogresponse = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to barter?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

System.out.println(ogresponse);

if (ogresponse == 0) {
    String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to buy items, sell items, or discard an item? (options: Sell, Buy, or Discard)").toLowerCase();
    do {

        if (response.equals("discard")) {

            String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to discard? (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol)").toLowerCase();
            remove_item(list, name_Item);

            int keep_Going = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to discard more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (keep_Going == 0) {
                stock();
                ogresponse = 0;
            } else if (keep_Going == 1) {
                ogresponse = 1;
            }
        }

        else if (response.equals("sell")) {

            String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to sell? (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol)").toLowerCase();
            String qty_Amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to sell?").toLowerCase();
            int qty_num = Integer.parseInt(qty_Amount);
            sell(list, name_Item, qty_num);

            int keep_Going = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to sell more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (keep_Going == 0) {
                stock();
                ogresponse = 0;
            } else if (keep_Going == 1) {
                ogresponse = 1;
            }

        } else if (response.equals("buy")) {

            String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to buy? (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol)").toLowerCase();
            String qty_Amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to buy?").toLowerCase();
            int qty_num = Integer.parseInt(qty_Amount);
            buy(list, name_Item, qty_num);
            int keep_Going = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to buy more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (keep_Going == 0) {
                stock();
                ogresponse = 0;
            } else if (keep_Going == 1) {
                ogresponse = 1;
            }

        }
    } while (ogresponse != 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a boolean.
If the user choose to barter egain, set the boolean to true and repeat the do-while. something like

```
 do{ 
      String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to buy items, sell items, or discard an item? (options: Sell, Buy, or Discard)").toLowerCase(); 
      //The rest of the code
      System.out.println("¿Repeat?");
      if(UserSaysYes){
      boolean=true;
      else{
      boolean=false;
      }

    }while((ogresponse != 1)||(boolean==true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I think i figured it out. I just had the program change response as well within each if statement.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things you can do to smooth out the code a bit.

First, I split out the "Would you like to ... more?" section. You can do this by either switching out  with a more generic term such as barter, or even listing out the options. If that doesn't appeal to you, then I would declare a variable `String operation = ""` and then set `operation` to discard, sell, or buy depending on the action that occurred. Then, at the end of the loop, you have the line

```
int keep_Going = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to " + operation + " more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Second, I would switch from relying on ogresponse directly, and go from a `do while` to a `while`. You can more easily store if you want to continue in a boolean variable. Saves you a (trivial) amount of memory, but also looks cleaner and is more clear on what you're doing. What you do with the `stock()` function depends on how it works. I'd put it at the front of the loop, because whenever the loop is accessed that means implicitly that a transaction is going to occur and you need your wares up to stock. That said, I don't know the details of that function. If we accept all those changes, we can take this code from

```
if(ogresponse == 0){
    do{
        /*your code here*/
        int keep_Going = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to discard more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (keep_Going == 0) {
            stock();
            ogresponse = 0;
        } else if (keep_Going == 1) {
            ogresponse = 1;
        }
        /*more code here*/
        int keep_Going = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to sell more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (keep_Going == 0) {
            stock();
            ogresponse = 0;
        } else if (keep_Going == 1) {
            ogresponse = 1;
        }
        /*yet more code here*/
        int keep_Going = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to sell more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (keep_Going == 0) {
            stock();
            ogresponse = 0;
        } else if (keep_Going == 1) {
            ogresponse = 1;
        }
    }while(ogresponse != 1)
}
```

to

```
boolean continueWithDialog = (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to barter?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == 0)
while(continueWithDialog){
    stock(); //You could put this after the dialog and add a check, if(continueWithDialog) if stock() is a particularly sensitive function.
    /*your code here*/
    continueWithDialog = (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to barter more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == 1);
}
```

You can also split out a lot of those lengthy `if` blocks into their own methods, resulting in a much cleaner main loop block. You could also do a switch statement, but I'm personally not a huge fan of `switch` over `if`.

```
while(continueWithDialog){
    stock();
    String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to buy items, sell items, or discard an item? (options: Sell, Buy, or Discard)").toLowerCase();
    if(response.equals("discard"))
        barter();
    else if(response.equals("sell"))
        sell();
    else if(response.equals("buy"))
        buy();
    else
        /*What if they don't enter one of the expected values?*/
    continueWithDialog = (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to barter more?", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == 1);
}
```

It may seem silly to split them out now, but if you ever need to reuse them, you'll be thankful you did! And even excluding reuse case, it provides a bit of clarity, as well as looking a bit neater.